# For which values of $x$ the limit $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty} (-1)^n \frac x{2^n}$ exists?

Tags: limits, sequence-of-function

> Let $f_1:[0,4]\to [0,4] $be defined by $f_1(x)=3-\frac x2$. Define $f_n(x) =f_1\left( f_{n-1}(x)\right)$ for $n\ge 2$. Find the set of all $x$ such that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty} f_n(x)$ exists and also find the corresponding limits.

**Try**
I find that $$f_n(x) =\frac 3{2^{n-1}}+(-1)^n \frac x{2^n}$$
Hence $$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty} f_n(x)=\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac 3{2^{n-1}}+\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty} (-1)^n \frac x{2^n} 
  =0+\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty} (-1)^n \frac x{2^n}=\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty} (-1)^n \frac x{2^n}$$ Hence the left hand side exists if the right hand side is so. From here I'm unable to find the values of $x$.
Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: $x$ is just a fixed constant and $(-1)^n 2^{-n} \to 0$

Comment: That means $x$ can be any real number?

Comment: All values of $f_1$ are between $1$ and $3$, and therefore so are all values of $f_n$ for every $n$.  In particular your formula for $f_n$ can't be right.

Comment: HINT: if you know Banach Fixed Point Theorem, you can argue that the sequence converges for all $x \in [0,4]$, since $f_1$ is a contraction. Moreoever the limit point is the unique fixed point, namely $x=2$. I post this as a comment, since it does not answer to the question in title, but it solves the problem in the body of the question.

Answer (score 2):

It is easy to show that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{2^n} = 0,$$
and since $x$ is independent of $n$, $\lim_{n\to\infty} x = x,$ so

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} (-1)^n \frac x{2^n} 
= \left(\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{2^n}\right) \left(\lim_{n\to\infty} x\right)
= 0 \cdot x = 0.$$

On the other hand,

\begin{align}
3 - \frac12\left(\frac 3{2^{n-1}}+(-1)^n \frac x{2^n}\right)
&= 3 - \left(\frac 3{2^n}+(-1)^n \frac x{2^{n+1}}\right) \\
&= 3 - \frac 3{2^n} + (-1)^{n+1} \frac x{2^{n+1}} \\
&\neq \frac 3{2^n} + (-1)^{n+1} \frac x{2^{n+1}} 
\end{align}

for any $n > 1.$
So you have some corrections to make in the calculations that got you your formula.

Answer (score 1):

$$f_n(x) = 2 \left[ 1- \left( -\frac12\right)^n\right]+(-1)^n \frac{x}{2^n}$$

For any finite number $x$, $$\lim_{n\to \infty} (-1)^n \frac{x}{2^n}=0$$since $2^n \to \infty$.

Your domain is $[0,4]$, everyone of them would satisfy the condition.

Note the first term of your $f_n$ is not right.